# Shibboleth SSO Configuration for Multi-Site

Tags: apache-http-server

I have a multisite application running in WordPress.  One of my customers recently asked for SSO for their org and specifically requested that I use shibboleth.  However, all of my other subdomains need to use the default login/registration pages native to my site.  I have installed shibboleth and have the SP authenticating with the IdP on a test server with one enabled site.  However, now as I move to multi site, I am unsure how I can "tell" the shibboleth apache module to protect content based on the request HTTP request.

For example, lets assume sp.shibboleth.com is using SSO and sp1.shibboleth.com is NOT using SSO.  However, the pages displayed for each subdomain are the exact same with the content living in the same directory.  How would I go about configuring shibboleth to be active for the sp subdomain but not for the sp1 subdomain?

Thanks.

Comment: They're still served by a different Apache virtualhost, aren't they?

Answer (score 0):

For Apache, you enforce Shibboleth usage through options very similar to HTTP Basic auth, and similarly they can be set at VirtualHost level, such as:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName site1.example.com

    # Useful to distinguish multiple sites within shibboleh.xml
    # (for giving them different entityIDs)
    <Location />
        ShibRequestSetting applicationId site1
    </Location>

    <Location /Shibboleth.sso>
        SetHandler shib
    </Location>

    # The actual path you want to protect
    <Location /wp-whatever>
        AuthType Shibboleth
        ShibRequestSetting requireSession On
        Require shib-session
    </Location>
</Location>
```

Options in this VirtualHost will have no effect on any of your other vhosts.

(Note: This is for Shibboleth SP 3.x – I think it used to be `Require valid-user` in SP 2.x.)